# Background video too big

Tags: html, css, video, background, responsive

screenshot on phone

[image: on phone]

screenshot on PC

[image: on laptop]

This is a video in a background.

the problem.

 when the website is on fullscreen the video size is to big. I tried to make it smaller with margin top . but its cuts the video in half. the video has to stay in the orginal conditon on full screen and smal screen. how do I do this?

```
<body>

    <div id="videoContainer" class="half-black">
        <div class="videoWrapper">
            <video autoplay>
                <source src="video/warwick.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoContainer" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #videoContainer{
    height:auto;
    background-color:darkslateblue;
    border-bottom:5px solid black;
}
#infoContainer{
    background-color:dodgerblue;
    height:40%;
}

.videoWrapper > video {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:-35%;


}
.videoWrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `object-fit` CSS property to fit the video in its container.
Use and see if this solves your problem. Also, no need of margin property.

```
.videoWrapper > video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: tnx bro it helped!